# The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) LocalTime, int in java

Tags: java, datetime

I have this code here:

[image: code]

But I get the error message:

> The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s)LocalTime, int

Why is that? How can I fix the code?

Here is the code again as text:

```java
import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Services {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        LocalTime t = LocalTime.now();
        
        if (t >=0 && t<12){
            System.out.println("Good Morning!");
        }
        else if (t>=12 && t<18)
        {
            System.out.println("Good Afternoon!");   
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Hello Neel ,how may I help you");  

               
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    LocalTime t = LocalTime.now();
    int h = t.getHour();
    if (h >= 0 && h < 12) {
        System.out.println("Good Morning!");
    } else if (h >= 12 && h < 20) {
        System.out.println("Good Afternoon!");
    } else {
        System.out.println("Hello Neel ,how may I help you");

    }
}
```

}**This worked for me**

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow and thanks for wanting to contribute. While your code is correct, your answer could need some explanation. Even of you don’t want to answer the *Why is that?* part of the question, please still explain how your code works.

Answer (score 4):

### Comparing objects

You can not use `<` on anything else than primitives like `int`. Use `compareTo` instead.

Like `first.compareTo(second)`, the result is either

- negative (if smaller),
- `0` (if equals) or
- positive greater 0 (if greater).

So the equivalent of to `first < second` would be `first.compareTo(second) < 0`.

---

### Comparing `LocalTime` in particular

For the **java.time** API, there are also special methods like `isBefore` and `isAfter` which make this comparison even simpler.

---

### `LocalTime` vs `int`

Also, you can not compare a high level object such as `LocalTime` to a plain `int`. Have a look at

```java
LocalTime.of(12, 0)
```

and similar methods instead.

There are also some special pre-created constants, such as `LocalTime.MIDNIGHT` and `LocalTime.NOON`.

---

### Putting everything together

If you follow both advices, the fixed code could look like:

```java
LocalTime t = LocalTime.now();

if (t.isAfter(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT) && t.isBefore(LocalTime.NOON)) {
  System.out.println("Good Morning!");
} else if (t.isAfter(LocalTime.NOON) && t.isBefore(LocalTime.of(18, 0))) {
  System.out.println("Good Afternoon!");   
} else {
  System.out.println("Hello Neel, how may I help you"); 
}
```

Ideally you could also introduce a quick helper method such as

```java
private static boolean isBetween(LocalTime start, LocalTime time, LocalTime end) {
  return time.isAfter(start) && time.isBefore(end);
}
```

to simplify the code further:

```java
LocalTime t = LocalTime.now();

if (isBetween(LocalTime.MIDNIGHT, t, LocalTime.NOON)) {
  System.out.println("Good Morning!");
} else if (isBetween(LocalTime.NOON, t, LocalTime.of(18, 0))) {
  System.out.println("Good Afternoon!");   
} else {
  System.out.println("Hello Neel, how may I help you"); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The straightforward way to translate your code into something that works is

```
 LocalTime t = LocalTime.now();
 int h = t.getHour();
```

and then compare 'h'.

For more complicated cases, for example if you wanted to check whether it was before 12:30, look into constructions like

```
 t.isBefore(LocalTime.of(12, 30))
```

or possibly

```
 !LocalTime.of(12, 30).isAfter(t);
```

(The two differ in the decision of the exact time 12:30)

Comment: LocalTime t = LocalTime.now();
 int h = t.getHour();                                                                                                                                    yes this one worked for me thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well this was very useful! I'm a beginner myself and was playing around with the if statements. With the help of the answers I managed to scramble something simple:

import java.time.LocalTime;

public class Main {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LocalTime currentTime = LocalTime.now();

    System.out.println("The current time is "+currentTime);

    int hour = currentTime.getHour();
    int timeOfDay = 10;

    if (hour >= 0 && hour < 12) {
        System.out.print("Good Morning!");
    } else if (hour >= 12 && hour < 18) {
        System.out.print("Good Afternoon!");
    } else {
        System.out.print("Good Evening!");
    }
}
```

}

since "isBetween" did not work in the Main Class